# Enums behave differently in two separate files

Tags: c++, enums, klocwork

I am facing very absurd issue, with enums usage in cpp source. I am just sharing the section, where issue is.

I have an enum declared in a header file, as: **< type.h >**

```
 enum type{
    BT_PLAY,
    BT_DEACT
    };
```

Next is the file **< com.cpp >**, usage is as:

```
#include <type.h>
...
void sendmsg(unsigned short requestId, char* json)
{
  ..
  void *data = Conv::doConvertReq(requestId, json, size);
  ...
  if(NULL != data){
    if(BT_PLAY == requestId){
      delete [](char*)data;
      data = NULL;

    } else{
        delete data;
        data = NULL;
    }

  }
}
```

Next is the file **< conv.cpp >**, whose API is getting called in the **< com.cpp >**. Usage is as;

```
void*
Conv::doConvertReq(unsigned short requestId, const char* json, int& size){

  switch(requestId){
  ...
  case BT_PLAY:
  {
     char *val = new char[10];
     data = (void*) val;
     break;
  }
  case BT_DEACT:
  {
    struct *btDeact = new BT_T();
    data = (void*) btDeact;
    break;
  }
  ...
}
```

Now, when I am analyzing the code using **KLOCWORK**, I see leak reported as;

*Freeing mismatched memory from 'data'. Memory referenced by 'data' allocated through function 'doConvertReq' at line 70 is illegally freed by passing argument 1 to function 'delete[]'*

While tracing through traceBlocks, it says the condition as:

- for case **BT_DEACT**, in file **conv.cpp**, the de-allocation is done in **"BT_PLAY == requestId"** case inside **sendmsg(...)** API of **com.cpp** file.

There does not seem to be any case, where this would fit in, however klocwork reports this. And no leaks, as analyzed by valgrind, for the same code setup.
Any clue, for this possibility??

Comment: Come up with a _complete, minimal testcase_ that reproduces the issue. More often than not this is the debugging step that allows you to figure out what's wrong.

Comment: Removed. I concur with LRO, post a compilable test-case (*compilable for us*).

Comment: On a side note, I'd recommend that if you provide API to allocate a resource, you also provide API to deallocate it. `delete`ing something returned from an API is a code smell in my book.

Comment: `struct *btDeact =` does that compile - there's no type specified?  And anyway, you're `delete`ing it as a `void*` which won't invoke the `BT_T` destructor.

Comment: Dunno if this is the issue, but you need to `delete (BT_T*)data;` in your sendmsg second block;

Comment: A test-case would be as, "sendmsg(BT_DEACT,"");". But in the dynamic scenario, the reported case by the klocwork, can never be realized, and do does it never happen.

Comment: It seems, that the "klocwork" is confused, as it gets a void* return value, that gets de-allocated later over condition. And as per compilation flow, for the Conv::doConvertReq(..), it sees a possibility of returned "void*" as a (struct*), and hence complains of the situation, that might end up freeing the (struct*) value as (char*). something pointed by @StoryTeller .